iOS18， When previewing, the preview and video frames freeze when the flashlight is turned on, but return to normal when the flashlight is turned off
iOS18， When previewing, the preview and video frames freeze when the flashlight is turned on, but return to normal when the flashlight is turned off
Is there a solution? We are currently considering it?

Welcome to Stack Overflow @sunjiachen! For this question, could you provide some more context? Such as the language your using, and your code? :)

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

After iOS 18, the acquisition of AVCapture Device will affect the flashlight and video frames and previews. If two AVCapture Devices are not the same, the video frames and previews will freeze when the flashlight is turned on. After turning it off, restore it. Solution: Use the same AVCapture Device for the flashlight and video frames and previews
